XML Name property not working on first node in Genexus
I Have an SDT like this, called SDTInserimentoPackage

I want to create an xml from it, but I want to change the name of the first node

But it isn't working. I tried to set that property also in another node, like this

it works here, but not in the first node

Whatever I try, the first node of the xml is always in the name of the SDT. I could replace it by hand from the text, but I would like to know if I'm doing something wrong or if there is no way to change the behavior of the first node

First level can change with the "Exposed name" property. Property of the SDT object, not in structure definition.
This SDT

with this

obtain this:


Thanks, I thought I tried it, but evidently I missed it
